# Cucumber use custom formatter for logging

Tags: java, html, format, cucumber, formatter

I'm programming with java and want to use another formatter than the common "pretty" one.

Currently I'm using

```
@CucumberOptions(
format = {"pretty",
           "html:"+ LOGGING_PATH})
```

I've already found this here:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters
but this seems to be just for ruby.

I want to add some information like the current time and some more actions from the WebDriver.

I know I can add some text or images between the cucumber created logs, like in https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#screenshots described for java.

If anybody has the same problem or knows how to use one of the Custom-Formatters that already exist from the above mentioned github project, I'll be very thankful to get some useful suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: You can do same with Java using log4j and others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how do I get the events for step definitions like for "Feature" or "Scenario"? So I can save them to the log file, like the pretty html formatter does?
Furthermore I want to save the "Given", "When" and "Then" steps.

Comment: Hi @user24502, Could you find how to achieve this